# IOS - Request for member 'domain' not a structure or union?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get token from cookie. When I do I get an error like:

"Request for member 'domain' not a structure or union"

```
- (NSString*)getTokenFromCookie {
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
        if ([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:self.domain]) {
            if ([[cookie name] isEqualToString:@"oauth_token"]) {
                return [cookie value];
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Where and how have you declared `domain`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of `self.domain`

You probably haven't declared it as an `@property`, or `self` is not what you think it is.